# Auto update changeset hook fails with status -1

Tags: windows, network-share, mercurial, hook

I am using Mercurial SCM over a LAN using a normal shared folder instead of HTTP. I'm having a problem getting the auto update hook to run.

I have entered this hook as [detailed in the FAQ](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2BAC8-CommonProblems.Any_way_to_.27hg_push.27_and_have_an_automatic_.27hg_update.27_on_the_remote_server.3F). This installs the hook, but when I push something to the remote repository I get an error:

```
added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files
running hook changegroup: hg update >&2
warning: changegroup hook exited with status -1
```

There is a [similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885246/mercurial-auto-update-problem), but it offers no solutions other than it may be a permissions error somewhere.

Has anyone else had this problem and can anyone else shed any more light on this or give me a heads up on where to start fixing this? Could it be a problem with server permissions?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606470/mercurial-changeset-hook-problem-when-auto-updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with

```
[hooks]
changegroup = hg update --debug
```

instead. The redirection of errors might trip up something with certain old versions of Mercurial. Then also try pushing with

```
$ hg push --debug
```

to get all available output from Mercurial.